# Not all data is being saved in the array through mysqli_fetch_array() function when I try to echo each index

Tags: php, mysqli

Not all data is being saved in the array through mysqli_fetch_array() function when I try to echo each index. I want to store all table names inside of an array variable called `$tablas` So I'm trying to gather all the table names using the `mysqli_fetch_array()`. I have 4 tables stored in the datable so I was using a `print_r()` but it was only showing for the index of 0, then I tried with a `var_dump()` but did the same. So I wanted to find out if table names are actually being saved into the `$table` array so then I tried with using `echo` instead for each index in the array as shown below but only is working for index 0 others seem not to exist. What is causing this?

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","capacitacion");
    $consulta = "SHOW TABLES FROM capacitacion";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    if($resultado){
        $tablas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
        echo $tablas[0];
        echo $tablas[1];
        echo $tablas[2];
    }
    else{
        echo 'error';
    }
?>
```

Comment: [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) only returns a single row at a time.

Comment: Take a look at [fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), that might do what you want to do.

Comment: I did it with the fetch_all and now the error show is Array to string conversion. how to I fix it?

Comment: use `var_dump($tablas)` to debug the structure of your array, you will see it is compose of many items (array themselves), so you probably have to loop over `tablas` if you want to handle this case.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.